# modprobe inside an LXC container

Tags: linux, virtualization, lxc, modprobe

I need to run a WebDAV server inside of an LXC container, but I'm being told that modprobe is not available (even as root).  I've seen that this was requested by developers, but how can I get around it?

Running on Debian Squeeze.

Here's the messages I'm getting after loading dav2fs on the main server:

```
Please enter the username to authenticate with server
http://10.102.42.101/owncloud/files/webdav.php or hit enter for none.
  Username: lwapnitsky
Please enter the password to authenticate user lwapnitsky with server
http://10.102.42.101/owncloud/files/webdav.php or hit enter for none.
  Password:
/sbin/mount.davfs: sh: 1: can't open fuse device
/sbin/modprobe: not found/sbin/mount.davfs:
trying coda kernel file system
sh: 1: /sbin/modprobe: not found
/sbin/mount.davfs: no free coda device to mount
```

Comment: What kernel module do you need for WebDAV? Is this not a plain apache httpd module?

Comment: davfs2 for webdav file sharing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LXC is - according to its own [home-page](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/) “chroot on steroids”. So basically you do use the "main" kernel (outside the container) - not - like in virtualization - your "own" kernel.

So if you really need a certain kernel-module this has to be loaded on your LXC-server.

Comment: let me try loading that on the main server.  forgot about that.